# Writing a query to display data from two different tables

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to put one Column as "VendorName" from the Vendors table, and one column as InvoiceAverage from the InvoiceTotal column in the Invoices table. I'm trying to average the invoice totals for each vendor in the table

```
SELECT InvoiceTotal
FROM Invoices
GROUP BY Invoices.InvoiceTotal
ORDER BY AVG(InvoiceTotal)
```

Is as far as i've got and it doesn't give me anything that I want

Comment: How do the two tables relate? If you were to put `vendors INNER JOIN Invoices` what would you put after the `ON` clause?  To make this clear, please provide example data for both tables.  So we can see how the data is structured, and how the data is related.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you join on a field VendorId:

```
SELECT v.VendorName, AVG(i.InvoiceTotal) AS InvoiceAverage
FROM Invoices i
    JOIN Vendors v ON i.VendorId = v.VendorId
GROUP BY v.VendorName
ORDER BY AVG(i.InvoiceTotal)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select VendorName, avg(InvoiceTotal) as 'some column name'
from Invoices
group by VendorName
-- order by avg(InvoiceTotal) desc/ asc
```

You want to group by the value that you're averaging over. That's how it works.

Comment: The OP mentions a Vendors table, where are you using a Vendors table?